# how to debug repeater control?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Is it possible to set a break point in the html of the aspx user control page at the following point 
(code given here for example):

```
< repeater blah blah >  
< span > <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "myvalue") % > < / span >  (break here)  
< / repeater etc >
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008.
I know I can look at the dataview that is bound to the repeater control in debug mode but I would prefer to see this  "as it happens" as in some cases I get an error where a cast is not working properly. So I guess I am asking if we can get into and "see" the `Container.DataItem` value in the loop as it is being run.

many thanks, John

Comment: Use the Repeater's [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)-Event. Swap out the databinding there and you can debug the values in codebehind.

Answer (score 4):

You could add an event handler for `ItemDataBound` on the repeater control in your codebehind file.

In the `RepeaterItemEventArgs` that is passed, you can access `e.Item.DataItem`, which is the same as `Container.DataItem` in your code. Using the debugger's immediate window you can then test the values.

E.g.:

Page.ascx

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_Databound">
...
</asp:Repeater>
```

Page.ascx.cs

```
protected void Repeater1_Databound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Breakpoint here - use immediate window or
    // watch to examine contents of the 'item' variable.
    var item = e.Item.DataItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot debug the design view.
OnItemDataBound can be used to debug in code behind.